# Структура, архитектура JVM(внутреннее устройство), от .java до .jar?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, Возникла необходимость и желание понять внутреннее устройства JVM.
То как создаётся байт код и то что он является входной информацией JVM машины, я понимаю. 
Но после того, как он поступает в JVM, для меня глухой лес.
Как я нагуглил, там имеется верификатор байт-кода, сборщик мусора, менеджер безопасности, интерпретатор /JIT компилятор.
Как они работают, в какой последовательности, и как взаимодействую мне не понятно.
Гуглил, искал, читал по частям, но нигде не нашёл схемы или сути того как это выглядит по шагам всё вместе.
Буду вам благодарен, если объясните, расскажите.
Также если имеются какие либо статьи с описанием этого процесса или книги, буду вам благодарен за наводки.
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Нормальный ответ будет размером в хорошую книгу.

Comment: Я не требую чего-то фундаментального, мне хватит и 10 предложений описывающих по шагам краткую суть внутренностей jvm.
Пример: jvm получает байт код, первым делом с ним встречается верификатор, который делает, тото, после запускается второй поток сборщика, и т.д.

Comment: Подойдет статья из oracle docs? она правда на английском
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html

Comment: Нашёл её до вашей ссылки в переводе на русский, но прочитав её не почерпнул того что я искал. хотя, возможно стоит ещё раз прочесть.

Comment: @den, честно говоря, первый раз, читая про JVM, почти ничего не понял.
Со временем, некоторые моменты прояснились. Помогло чтение подобной документации

Comment: Суть я понимаю, но не могу всё систематизировать и разложить на полочки.

Answer (score 3):

на вход JVM подается classpath - список директорий и jar-файлов, где искать классы, и имя стартового класса. JVM находит класс-файл стартового класса и загружает его, то есть раскладывает по компонентам (основные компоненты - методы, константы и статические переменные), верифицирует (проверяет, что байткод удовлетворяет многочисленным ограничениям, например не модифицирует указатели и не использует целые в качестве булевских), инициализирует статические переменные и запускает метод main(String[]). Методы сначала исполняются интерпретатором. Если интерпретатор обнаруживает, что метод используется часто, то он передает его JIT'у, получаеет нативный код и в дальнейшем вызывает его. Если во время исполнения встречается ссылка на другой класс, этот класс точно также загружается, верифицируется и инициализируется. Все остальное - детали.